# How to display a notification when my application is in background?

Tags: java, android, notifications, background, broadcastreceiver

​I am trying to build an Android application that has -

a **First Activity** (*Launcher activity*)

and a **Second Activity**

***What I am trying to achieve :***

First Actvity takes an input from user , fetches data from web using an *AsyncTaskLoader* .
 In the *onLoadFinished* it checks if input is valid and if it is starts an Intent to Second Activity to sh​​ow more details . The input is also passed along with the Intent .

Since the network operation can take time so I decided to show a notification using *IntentService* just before Second Activity is created i.e. the notification is being called in *onLoadFinished* just before the Intent . The notification should directly start the Second Activity if it isn't already started .

***What is working fine :***

Both activities and the loader are working fine . The notification is also being displayed and everything is working as expected provided user keeps the app running .

***What isn't :***

When the user navigates away from First Activity while data is being loaded the notification is not shown because *onPause* is executed . I tried searching for it and got to know about *BroadcastReceiver* , *JobScheduler* and  *FirebaseJobDispatcher* but I can't really understand them and how they help .

So , am I on the right track ? And how can I achieve the same functionality even if app goes into background ?

P.S. The code is much more vast than the problem suggests so I didn't include it . That's why if explanation seems incomplete or messy I will try my best to clarify your doubts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work without using a BroadcastReciever or Service so those of you who are unfamiliar with them can take reference from this but ***use it your it at your own discretion*** as Services and Recivers are the recommended way to do it .

```
@Override
public void deliverResult(Data data) {
    super.deliverResult(data);
    showNotification(input);
}
```

This is a method in AsyncTaskLoader which is triggered after data is obtained . Override  it and alter the method of your notification that responds to notification click .

```
private PendingIntent onClick(Context context) {
     return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, ExtraActivity.class).
putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,input),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

The ExtraActivity is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288301/resume-background-activity-on-notification?rq=1) . It allows your notification to respond even if activity has been closed but the notification hasn't .

Again this is only a workaround for this specific situation which leads to me to pass around the input variable in many places and so it may not be as efficient performance-wise as other options .

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are on the right track.

Here is a sample from a map downloader I made. I hope you don't mind, but since you gave no context, I had to find a suitable example.

```
/**
* @param entry the map entry to be downloaded
* @return returns a receiver that unzips the map file after downloading
*/
private BroadcastReceiver createMapReceiver(MapEntry entry) {
     return new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             unregisterReceiver(this); // we unregister this receiver after the download is complete
             receiveDownloadedFile(entry); // once we receive the map file, we run this function, but you can do whatever you want. This is the part of the code youn were asking for
         }
     };
}


void downloadMap() {

    // preparing the download
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = createMapReceiver(entry); // see function above

  DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

  String downloadURL = fileListURL + entry.getFileName() + fileExtension; // building the url for the map
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadURL));

  if (manager != null) {
      manager.enqueue(request
              .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(areaFolder, entry.getFolderName())))
                    .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle("Some title, preferably taken from Strings.xml")
                    .setDescription("Some Description")
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            );
        } else {
            // if we couldn't find the DownloadManager
            onFailure(entry); // we simply run some onFailure function
        }

    }
```

Don't forget the permissions.

Comment: Upvoted . But if i register it in onLoadFinished of AsyncTaskLoader it wouldn't be executed when activity is in background and i need to validate input based on data returned . So where should i register the reciever ?

Comment: If what you need to do is too complex, you should encapsulate all this behaviour in a Service. Services are exactly that: Code that runs on background even when the app is hidden. Take a look at the documentation. If you still need help after that. I'd be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Register a Broadcast receiver through LocalBroadcastManager, and define filters. Now depending on filters you can play with UI elements or intents.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("A");
    filter.addAction("B");
    filter.addAction("C");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(dummyReceiver, filter);



private BroadcastReceiver dummyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
          //Do your work**
 }}
```

Try this. I have implemented this and it works.

Comment: Upvoted . But if i register it in onLoadFinished of AsyncTaskLoader it wouldn't be executed when activity is in background and i need to validate input based on data returned . So where should i register the reciever ?

Comment: If you have some button click or some action to be taken, so register the receiver on the action and perform your async task and everything inside this.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I achieve the same functionality even if app goes into background

use [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) or [intent services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service). 
intent service allow you to perform actions asynchronously.
bound services can provide interface using [aidl](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl). as long as the service is bound, it will be less likely destroyed. there are various ways to bind service using flags.

imho, activity is just a way of displaying UI. if you need any background work, use services.
when working with bound services via aidl, you will have to extend [service connection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection). it will receive the interface from service after binding.